Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the path Laplacian
Consider the Laplacian matrix of the path graph:
$$
L = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I want to find the eigendecomposition of this matrix. As far as I know, there are no general formulas for bisymmetric tridiagonal matrices. It's almost Toeplitz and I know the formula for tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices.
Any resources or pointers for this?

Can you confirm that the signs of the matrix entries are correct?

The off diagonals were flipped, thank you for pointing it out.

And can you confirm the entries top left and bottom right are really 1?

Yes, this is the difficulty. The endpoints of the path have degree 1.

This is the same as a StackExchange question that points to a complete solution by Jiang.

This solution quotes a set of lectures that I have already found, but that proof is not clear.
